# What LEGO cases are available for phones?

Tags: accessories

I would love to have a LEGO case for my HTC Desire that have LEGO compatible knobs so I can attach LEGO brick on it. Be free to post answers for LEGO case that is for other phones as well, as this is probably something that is interesting for everyone - not only those with HTC Desire...

<sub>Someone has taken the drastic move to [make their own](http://www.totalgeekdom.com/?p=288)... I don't want to sacrifice LEGO bricks like that...</sub>

Comment: Nice suggestion in the link, but involves gluing LEGO which is seen by many users of this site as a crime!! :-)

Comment: @mcqwerty: and I agree. I changed the text around the link to express this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure such a case exists for the HTC Desire.
All of the LEGO *style* phone accessories I have seen in the past have been for the iphone.

A bit of searching turned up these items:

What appears to be a case with LEGO compatible studs (for iphone)
[image: iphone LEGO case]

[Check out this page](http://www.1finecookie.com/2011/09/gadgets-gizmos-and-other-random-crap-lego-edition/) for other LEGO relates accessories and a picture of the above case in use with actual LEGO built onto it (near the bottom of the page).

There is also a [TinkerBrick LEGO iPod/iPhone 3 case](http://blog.makezine.com/2012/07/27/tinkerbrick-lego-compatible-iphone-case/) which has studs on the front and sockets on the back. There are taking Votes for the next supported phone [on their site](http://tinkerbrick.com/).

There is a mock LEGO silicone iphone case [available here](http://www.etsy.com/listing/105309733/multicolor-lego-phone-case?ref=sr_gallery_6&ga_search_query=lego%20phone&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_ship_to=ZZ&ga_min=0&ga_max=0&ga_page=1&ga_search_type=all). The two pieces can be attached in different positions.

[image: Silicone iphone case]

To wander off topic slightly, there are other 'phone related' LEGO *style* accessories available that are compatible with most phones:

[image: Dock cover]

[Dock cover available here](http://www.etsy.com/listing/98923179/modified-lego-flowers-as-iphone-ipod?ref=sr_gallery_13&ga_search_query=lego%20phone&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_ship_to=ZZ&ga_min=0&ga_max=0&ga_page=1&ga_search_type=all).

[image: Earphones]

[LEGO brick earphones available here](http://www.japantrendshop.com/elecom-sundries-playbrick-p-812.html).